# Reduce type parameter

Tags: java, generics

In a abstract class, I have

```
public abstract class BaseService<T, R extends BaseDto<ID>, ID extends Object> {
    ...
}
```

Instead of passing three param, i would like to pass two, to do something like

```
public abstract class BaseService<T, R extends BaseDto<ID extends Object>> 
{
    ...
}
```

I get this error

```
> expected
'{' expecte
wrong number of type arguments; required 1
```

Comment: Which line produce this error?

Comment: At least you can remove `extends Object`

Comment: Is ID a class or generic type parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't implicitly declare new generic parameters. So no way to do what you want.

Only option you have is wildcard parameter.

```
class BaseService<T, R extends BaseDto<? extends Object>>
```